# Декодирование в JSON из datetime.date

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть сервис и есть база. Надо проверить что сервис получает то же, что отдает база. Из сервиса GET-запросом получаю JSON. А вот от базы вот такое:

```
(datetime.date(2019, 3, 18), 20)
(datetime.date(2019, 3, 19), 20)
(datetime.date(2019, 3, 20), 20)
(datetime.date(2019, 3, 21), 20)
```

Как мне декодировать это в JSON?

Код:

```
r = requests.get(url)
recv = r.content.decode('utf-8')
print(r.status_code)
print(recv)

print("Opened database successfully")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select.......")
record = cursor.fetchall()
for dat in record:
    print(dat)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [данном вопросе на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable) представлены все более менее элегантные способы сериализации `date` / `datetime` в JSON.

Вот один из самых коротких вариантов:

```
In [89]: print(json.dumps(items, indent=2, default=str))
[
  [
    "2019-03-18",
    20
  ],
  [
    "2019-03-19",
    20
  ],
  [
    "2019-03-20",
    20
  ],
  [
    "2019-03-21",
    20
  ]
]
```